# Solr field UUID is not unique

Tags: solr, plone

I'm running Solr 5.1.0 on our Plone 4.2.6 system. In my `schema.xml` I set UID to be the uniqueKey. On the system there are approx 82.000 documents. After building an Index, I found the following amount of indexed docs:

`numDocs: 54537
maxDocs: 82561
deletedDocs: 28024`

Furthermore under 'core-specific-tools > Schema Browser > Load Term Info > Histogram' I found that for the field UID there are 26,514 values of UID contained in only one document but also 28,022 values contained in 2 documents. Therefore that amount of indexed documents were tagged as deletable.

Can anyone tell me what reason there could be for that many UIDs to be the same although they should be distinct?

Comment: I don't know, but have read the Article of uuid vs.uid in the [Plone Docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/uid.html#id4).

Comment: A possibility for non-unique UIDs could be, that content of several Plone-sites have been mashed up together into one site. Maybe using __U__UIDs for the uniqueKey instead, serves better.